# Laravel - How can I put a list of items in order?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am thinking of creating a website to sell courses online, and each individual course there will be a class order to be followed.

A good example of this is [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/), in each [course](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017) there is a sequence of lessons to be followed.

Basically I Will have two models: `Course` and `Episode`

`Episode` belongsTo `Course`

Every episode need to be linked with the previous and the next episode.

Can someone show me the correct way to put certain items in order in the database?

Creating a column named `order` is the best alternative?

Comment: would you give more hints on what are the requirements from the `class order`?

Answer (score 0):

Any column that stores an integer will work here whether it's named 'order', 'lesson', 'episode', or whatever you like.

When you want to retrieve it you will then use an orderBy clause

```
$course->lessons()->orderBy('episode', 'asc')
```

Comment: The problem is, let's assume that I first register episode 20, and a few weeks later I resolve to update the content and another episode needs to be 20, how can I change an order of all items in that course?

Comment: You would need to write a custom method to handle that, likely in the course class. Method would take a lesson and episode #, grab all episodes in the course that are >= the number you are going to insert, and increment that by 1.